# Windows 10 UWP Update Task

Tags: windows, winrt-xaml, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

In Windows 8 (Phone) there was an ability to run a background task when your app got upgraded. Trying to decipher the Windows 10 documentation, but it doesn't appear obvious if this functionality exists in Windows 10.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn673541.aspx

Does anyone have suggestions on when/where you should run app migration logic in windows apps?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what happened to the **Update Task**, I'm solving the same problem now, but you can use Trigger with [SystemTriggerType.ServicingComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224839) for launching Background Task when the app is updated.
How to use it is shown in this [oldish sample for Windows 8](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9), it should work in UWP apps as well.